# What does it mean that after withdrawal of arxiv paper 'previous versions can still be retrieved'?

Tags: publications, arxiv

I'm considering withdrawing an arxiv paper (it has some errors, I think a fresh start is the way to go) but I'm confused about the warning that 'previous versions can still be retrieved' - will these be at least as difficult to retrieve as the (soon to be withdrawn) most recent version? (I looked at a few related questions but they didn't seem to address this specific question - e.g. [Substantial update of an arXiv paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5316/substantial-update-of-an-arxiv-paper), [Made an arXiv submission too early; How to minimize the damage?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13644/made-an-arxiv-submission-too-early-how-to-minimize-the-damage))

If the most recent withdrawn paper became harder to find that the older versions, that would not look like a good outcome to me.  I doubt that the latter is the case (it would be silly) but I want to confirm this before going ahead.  Thanks very much.

Comment: As the meme says, "one does not simply remove things from the internet".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0848) is an example of an arXiv paper that has been withdrawn.

You can see that if someone visits the non-version-specific URL, http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0848, they will see a notice that the article is withdrawn. There is still a link to the previous version(s), which they can click on to see the original paper:

[image]

If someone clicks on the link to the first version, or visits the version-specific URL, http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0848v1, they will see the original paper without any withdrawal notice.

(You can see other examples of withdrawn arXiv papers with [this Google query](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:arxiv.org+%22This+paper+has+been+withdrawn%22)).

Comment: Thanks, could that author add  a withdrawal notice for the earlier version?  I'm a little worried that in my case, with this set up, some one who wasn't quite up to speed with archiv might end up downloading the earlier version through failing to note the withdrawn notice on the most recent.

Comment: @user3591496 Then that would be their own research failure, not yours.