# The editor of a jounal asked me to withdraw the ArXiv version of a paper and only upload it after acceptance. Is it possible to do that?

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv, withdraw

I submitted a paper to Elsevier recently. The editor told me that its similarity tool found more than 80% of word coincidence and sent me the report. I realized that the test actually referred to the same paper, specifically the version posted in Arxiv. I thought this was very odd because the Elsevier recommends uploading the manuscript by retrieving the sources directly from Arxiv, which is what I did. After explaining to the editor what happened, he asked me to withdraw the paper from Arxiv and only submit it again after acceptance.

I would like to know if it is possible to upload a new version of the paper on Arxiv after having withdrawn it. Has anyone ever had a similar situation before?

Comment: If you withdraw a paper from arXiv it can still be [retrieved and read](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/72169/17254) though, so it's not clear what the editor is hoping to achieve here. And Elsevier generally allows preprints as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It sounds like this editor doesn't know what he is doing.  The fact that two copies of the same paper exist has nothing to do with plagiarism.  In your situation, I would withdraw the paper from the journal and submit elsewhere.

Comment: Does the journal have an official preprint policy on their website?

Comment: Perhaps the editor isn't concerned about "self-plagiarism" but about the anonymity of the reviewing process.

Comment: Agreeing with @Anyon. Most likely, withdrawing the paper from the arXiv will not withdraw it from whatever automated plagiarism checker the editorial office is using!

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree with the comments of [@anyon](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/17254/anyon) and [@david-ketcheson](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/81/david-ketcheson). I'd suggest that you

1. point the editor to the guidelines regarding self-archiving of the journal and/or Elsevier in general and, if this fails,
2. contact your library, because there are people dealing with this kind of situations very often and they usually have (other) contact persons/options at the publisher.